# How to match multiline log entries with and without keywords (regex)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, multiline

My log file looks like this:

```
 *** DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:11:46.678 [sendTaskResponse] ID2200*     
 Creating object GUID=6b7582ba-eb8b-4084-b726-26901827f150

 *** ERROR 2015-03-18 12:11:46.912 [        23] ID2543      
 Details:
 System.IO.IOException: Incorrect WPDU: 22354
    w Devices.DlmsConnection.Connect(DeviceE device, AGPRSKeysAssocEnum user) in d:\current\csharp\AProject\ADriver\Devices\DeviceE.cs:row 1921
    w Devices.Device.Connect(AGPRSKeysAssocEnum user) in d:\A\current\csharp\AProject\ADriver\Devices\DeviceE.cs:row 522
    w A.Devices.DeviceE.InitTask(DelegatedObjectTask thisTask) in d:\A\current\csharp\AProject\ADriver\Devices\DeviceE.cs:row 252

 *** DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:11:46.929 [sendStatus] ID2200*     
 Sending XML N.F6.Data.F6ObjectStatusData

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <F6ObjectStatusData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <sourceId>2200</sourceId>
   <status>4</status>
   <statusText> </statusText>
   <timestamp>2015-03-18T11:11:46.6237699Z</timestamp>
 </F6ObjectStatusData>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <F6ObjectStatusData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <sourceId>2202</sourceId>
   <status>4</status>
   <statusText>Device ready</statusText>
   <timestamp>2015-03-18T12:11:21.7213456+01:00</timestamp>
 </F6ObjectStatusData>

 *** DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:11:47.263 [sendStatus] ID2200*     
 Posted Objects Count=2
```

1) I need to get every of those 4 log entries
so entry from line starting with ***
and every next lines that doesn't start with ***
2) I need log entries witch contains some keyword (for example word "AGPRSKeysAssocEnum" - 2nd log entry)

Offcourse it must be done with regex patterns.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working? In the meantime, look here for information on the Multiline Regex Option https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 string text = fctb.Text;
 string strRegex = @"(\*\*\* (.*?)(?=\*\*\* |\z))";                      // ANSWER #1 
 //string strRegex = @"(\*\*\* [^\*]+AGPRSKeysAssocEnum.*?)(?=\*\*\*|\z)"; // ANSWER #2
 Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Singleline);
 MatchCollection m = myRegex.Matches(text);
 foreach (Match sm in m)
 {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sm.Groups[1].Value);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new String('-', 100));
 }
```

**OR**
search entries with keyword first split your logs and then apply regex likethis to each log, for example:

```
string text = "Your log text";
IEnumerable<string> splittedLog = GetEntriesForLog(text);
string strRegex = @".*?AGPRSKeysAssocEnum.*|\z";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Singleline);

var entries = splittedLog.Where(entry => myRegex.IsMatch(entry)).ToList();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73355/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-voskresenskiy-how-to-match-multiline-log-entries-wi).